# Augmented Edge Connectivity Problem for a Weighted, Undirected Graph

Tags: algorithms, graphs

I have a **weighted, undirected graph**, $\mathcal{G}=(\mathcal{V}, \mathcal{E}, \mathcal{W})$. Let say that the edge connectivity value of my graph is $\lambda(\mathcal{G})=\alpha$.

> $\lambda(\mathcal{G})=\min \lambda(u,v) \ \forall \ u,v \in \mathcal{V}$
>
> $\lambda(u,v)=\min \sum_{i=1}^{n} w_{ij}\delta_{ij}$
>
> $\delta_{ij} = \begin{cases} 
>       1 & \text{ $(i,j)$ is an edge of the min cut,} \\
>       0 & \text{ otherwise.}
>    \end{cases}$
>
> $w_{ij} = \begin{cases} 
>       a_{ij} (\neq 0) & (i,j) \in \mathcal{E}\\
>       0 & \text{ otherwise.}
>    \end{cases}$

My target is to increase the edge-connectivity value to $\gamma \ (>\alpha)$ by augmenting minimum edge weight value.

I posted a [related problem](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/53143/edge-connectivity-of-a-weighted-undirected-graph) a couple of days back. Someone pointed out that the problem is known as *Augmented Edge Connectivity* problem. I went through some literature. I came across lots of theorems, but could not find any implementation (in term of an algorithm).

Any kind of insight will be helpful.

Comment: Is your problem that no results you found were algorithmic, or that you could find no implementation for the algorithms you did find?

Comment: I saw a seminal paper by Andres Frank on this topic, but the implementation details are not there. I also went through some other papers but did not find any implementation details for this problem.

Comment: What is the question here? A reference request for an algorithm? A better question would be about a specific issues you've been having with the literature. (Note that complexity-/graph-theory-style papers often do not contain algorithms in easily recognizable form (i.e. pseudocode) even though they claim to propose an algorithm in the abstract. You'll have to piece it together from the paper yourself. Yes, I know. That said, you'll never find *all* the implementation detail in a (T)CS paper -- readers are expected to be able to fill in the necessary detail themselves.)

Comment: @Raphael, any good reference on this topic according to your opinion which exactly deals with a weighted, undirected graph.